# How to set image dpi using opencv in python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to set dpi to (72,72) using opencv in python. can anyone tell me how do we assign dpi in opencv using imwrite ?

```
img = cv2.imread('kitchen.jpeg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(500,500),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
rect = (10,10,500,500)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([0,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_white, upper_white) # could also use threshold
res = cv2.bitwise_not(img, img, mask)
cv2.imwrite('kitchen_processed.jpeg',img)
```

Comment: You rarely need to set the dpi unless doing high end printing - why do you think you need it?

Comment: You appear to be reading in a JPEG (which doesn't normally support transparency/alpha) and is in BGR order. You then try to convert it with `cvtColor()` from RGBA order to RGB. This seems rather wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

emm dpi is for printing only. during image write you dont have to do it or you cant do it(for some format). It's only at image print you have to do it. if you insist of doing so. After image write, call  System.call with the file name as the variable

```
convert -density 75 -units pixelsperinch infile.jpg outfile.png
```

normally the density is 300 or more. in your case, use it at 75

## edit

Add this in. Not sure if you have other potential problem. But based on your title, add this line should solve your issue

```
import subprocess


img = cv2.imread('kitchen.jpeg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(500,500),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
rect = (10,10,500,500)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([0,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_white, upper_white) # could also use threshold
res = cv2.bitwise_not(img, img, mask)
cv2.imwrite('kitchen_processed.png',img)
subprocess.run('convert -density 75 -units pixelsperinch kitchen_processed.png outfile.png')
```

Comment: I uploaded my code, can you please go through that?